# Question regarding application for multiple users

Tags: c#, sql, deployment, auto-update

I have developed an application as my college project using Visual Studio 2005 and SQL Server Express.  Up to five people evaluate the project.  At present I have installed it on everyone's machines.  However, when I update my application, I need to go to each machine and update the executable file.  There is a central server that can be accessed by all five at my college.
What I want to know is, is there a way where all of them can run the application simultaneously from the central server so that I do not need to run to everyone on campus to update it?  I want to update it at the server and be done with it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities:

- Start it directy from the fileshare (negative for network performance and complicated with security)
- Write your own updater - you can use the fileshare as source

If your migrating to 2008:

- Use WCF Services to send controls to the clients
- Your client programm can be small and dumb

And do not use ClickOnce unless you know what it does

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ClickOnceContentExpiratn.aspx